# How to use WinPcap in Xamarin (Forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms, winpcap

There are many .Net wrappers in C# for WinPcap like [SharpPcap](https://github.com/chmorgan/sharppcap) and [PcapDotNet](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net)

I have tried to add these Nuget packages to my Xamarin Forms projects but it does not work. I want to create a wifi/packet scanner but I am not sure how to do this in Xamarin. Is it even possible?

When I clone the GitHub repo and build my own version of SharpPcap, the application runs, but I get the error:

> System.DllNotFoundException: wpcap

The `wpcap.dll` is the dll that all these packages are wrapped around and use `[DllImport("wpcap.dll")]` to work. This wont work in Xamarin (I think).

Another way to use dll's is when you embed them as an application resource, is there any library which I can use that does that?

Answer (score 0):

> WinPcap consists of a driver, that extends the operating system to
>   provide low-level network access, and a library that is used to easily
>   access the low-level network layers. This library also contains the
>   Windows version of the well known libpcap Unix API.

Source: https://www.winpcap.org/

There is nothing impossible, however in mobile world you don't have that low level access to drivers and etc. unless you have a root on your device. It is unclear what exactly you want to build. But I know that on both iOS & Android there is an app called `Fing`. It scans your WiFi network for connected devices. It is written natively per platform. On Android there used to be many different applications that used MITM technique. For example `DroidSheep`. But I am not aware of any cross-platform solution that is able to scan the network or sniff packages.

Comment: Is there any way to do this in just Android? And how would I use the dll as an embedded resource?

Comment: Take a look on open source projects like https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery

Comment: The project is in Java but I need this to work in Xamarin (c#)